# Android/JSON Using retrieve and add element to a list

Tags: java, android, json, database, list

I'm building an app for 5 predefined users in order to learn android studio ,
I dont know how to use JSON files cause I just need it in my firebase to put data into it 
so here's the problem as u can see there are 5 users each one of theme has a list which users can put elements into it and other users can check those elements or not (The boolean variable)
 the problem is that I dont know how to access to my data to add an element to the list and modify the boolean variable from my java classes etc..

```
{
  "His data" : {
    "password" : "something",
    "username" : "someone",
    "list":[{
      "element": null,
      "Boolean":false
    } ]
  },
  "His data" : {
    "password" : "something",
    "username" : "someone",
    "list":[{
      "element": null,
      "Boolean":false
    }  ]
  },
  "her data" : {
    "password" : "something",
    "username" : "someone",
    "list":[ {
      "element": null,
      "Boolean":false
    } ]
  },
  "My data" : {
    "password" : "something",
    "username" : "someone",
    "list":[ {
      "element": null,
      "Boolean":false
    } ]
  },
  "her data" : {
    "password" : "something",
    "username" : "someone",
    "list":[{
      "element": null,
      "Boolean":false
    }  ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is perfect for transmitting data to / from an API or something but isn't really what you want when working in Java. Your going to want to define plain-old Java objects (POJOs) to pass around your app. Then use a library like GSON to translate to and from JSON for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firebase, you can actually read and write to the database using plain-old Java objects (POJOs) without the need of any library to convert from JSON to Java object and vice-versa.

Here is an example from the Firebase documentation. If you have an user POJO:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class User {

    public String username;
    public String email;

    public User() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
    }

    public User(String username, String email) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

You can add a new user using the following code:

```
private void writeNewUser(String userId, String name, String email) {
    User user = new User(name, email);

    mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user);
}
```

So you are basically saving the entire User object into your database. It makes the code cleaner because you do not need to convert any JSON or POJO to its counterpart, and it allows you to play with the objects instead of JSONs in your code.

Please refer to the [official Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data) if you need more details.

Comment: Thank you David , I've already tried this way to use data but when I add a new element to my list I go to firebase there is no element added I didnt understand why and when I want tu use this element I can use it with no problemes can you explain this ? Thank's for help =)